# Route Provider loading order in angular js

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, route-provider

I am using Require JS for dynamic loading controllers.

All my controllers and packages , html files are loading after app.js. But " We cannot add controllers, services, directives, etc after an application bootstraps."

My Problem is , I have added route porvider in app.js 
But the controllers and html are loading after app.js . SO I am getting controller is undefined issue. Please help me in this

Comment: You may want to take a look at [angular-require-lazy](https://github.com/nikospara/angular-require-lazy) which is an example project that does lazy loading of Angular components with the help of AMD modules.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a simple dependancy injection issue.

In my case I've got an app, which has a dashboard module. The dashboard module parents presentation modules. Each module has services, directives, controllers etc. You must properly inject them at the right place.

```js
//in app.js

var app = angular.module('App',[
  'App.constants',
  'App.modules.preloader',
  'App.modules.user',
  'App.modules.dashboard'
]);
```

```js
//in dashboard.module.js

var dashboardModule = angular.module('App.modules.dashboard',[
  'App.modules.dashboard.controllers',
  'App.modules.dashboard.services',
  'App.modules.dashboard.presentations.mileage',
  'App.modules.dashboard.presentations.speed',
  'App.modules.dashboard.presentations.summary'
]);
```

```js
//in speed.module.js
 
var speedModule = angular.module('App.modules.dashboard.presentations.speed',[
   'App.modules.dashboard.presentations.speed.controllers',
   'App.modules.dashboard.presentations.speed.services'
]);
```

Hope this helps!

If not, maybe post a bit more details about the issue. Some sample code and maybe a fiddle.